Does a magnet lose its magnetism?
I did review this question and answers, but I don't feel it explains it fully for me.
I have heard the claim from scientific educational sources that, say, a refrigerator magnet does indeed lose its magnetism just like a battery loses its charge, albiet over much longer time scales.
I can think of two main possibilities here:

A magnet will lose its charge over very long periods thermodynamically, because having magnetic domains and atoms randomly oriented is higher entropy than having them aligned.  So it "loses" its magnetism for the same reason that the magnet, battery, and all matter will eventually decay into radiation via entropic heat death. This could be what the claim refers to.

The magnet, like a battery, actually loses a bit of magnetism every time it attracts something, and so one being used often (say in a mechanism or motor) will lose its magnetism faster than one sitting static on a table.


If Option 2 is true, then the mechanism for this is unknown to me and I'd like to learn more about it.
At first glance it seems like a magnet works using a conservative force field, and if there are dissipative forces involved I'm not sure what they are (EM radiation, eddy currents, flexing or heating of the magnet as it deforms under loading?). Another key difference I see is that you can drive a motor with a battery, but you cannot drive one with a static magnet.
Hoping someone can shed light on this, specifically whether "using" a magnet makes it deplete faster in some way.

a "permanent" magnet is not in a thermodynamic equilibrium, e.g., at a constant temperature its free energy is not at a minimum, and a sufficiently large mechanical kick can shake its domains so that lose its "permanency". Its magnetized state is then only a local and not global minimum of its free energy and a sufficiently large spontaneous fluctuation may knock it off to its non-magnetized state that is the global minimum; you may also have to wait a few quadrillion years for that to happen, so for all intents and purposes a permanent magnet is permanent.

Can you expand on your magnet-battery analogy, or alternatively remove it entirely? I'm getting hung up on it and it's hard for me to figure out how to answer this without focusing on that. Batteries have been set up to use a chemical process to move charges, and that chemical process cannot be used indefinitely. Magnets do not operate in this same way. You keep saying magnets would lose magnetism in the same way batteries "lose its charge", and I don't follow that

Well, the claim magnets would lose magnetism in the same way batteries "lose its charge" is exactly the one I heard made, and I'm asking if it's valid and if so, how. I'll have to look for the original source, but it seemed like the implication was that the more it is "used," the faster it would deplete (like a battery).

So you're saying like... A fridge magnet stuck to the refrigerator would lose its magnetization faster than one resting on a wood table?

That, and/or one that was continually attached and removed from the fridge over and over, would lose magnetism faster than one lying on a wood table.  It's hard to articulate a claim that may be nonsense.

My intuition tells me it's no different than any other conservative force, like winding and unwinding a mousetrap, or raising a ball up and letting it fall again, repeatedly. Which doesn't make the ball or the Earth "deplete" its gravity. But I'm not sure about the magnet claim, hence the question.

The notion that a permanent refrigerator magnet in use would lose its magnetism faster than a static magnet makes no sense.

The permanent magnets in an electric motor are exposed to periodic magnetic fields at frequencies of a few Hz to thousands of Hz. A well designed motor operating well below the Curie point of these magnets can last for many decades (we certainly have 100+ year old examples). One can estimate that these magnets can withstand 10^12 magnetization cycles without losing most of their magnetization. One can most likely get even higher estimates out of magnetized electronic components operating at much higher frequencies.

The name for magnets that the analogous thing that electric charges would correspond to, would be the alignment of the magnetic domains. Entropy tends to randomise them and thus cause a loss of magnetisation. When you stick magnets together, there is an increase in alignment, and so that part is fine. However, when you pull the magnets apart, you are not doing it infinitely slowly, and the excess energy used can easily introduce new alignment mistakes, thus weakening the magnets. That's why heavily cycled/used magnets would demagnetise.


My intuition tells me it's no different than any other conservative force, like [...] raising a ball up and letting it fall again, repeatedly. Which doesn't make the ball or the Earth "deplete" its gravity

Your intuition is basically correct. When you stick the magnet to a steel surface or remove it, your arm is supplying the energy to move the magnet.
Your point #1 is also correct. A permanent magnet undergoes thermodynamic degradation, especially in the presence of a magnetic field that it isn't perfectly aligned to, and when subjected to vibrations, shocks, etc.
However, at typical Earth surface temperatures this thermodynamic degradation process is fairly slow, assuming the magnet's environment is relatively free of shocks and vibrations. For example, geologists can easily read ancient magnetic field lines that are preserved in rock formations, even though those rocks have undergone some physical stress. Paleomagnetists study field lines that are millions of years old.
Conversely, applying vibrations & shocks to a chunk of unmagnetised ferromagnetic material that's sitting in a magnetic field will magnetise it. Eg, get a steel pole and clamp it so that it's aligned to the Earth's magnetic field. (You can use a suspended magnetised needle to determine the exact vector at your location). Then hit the end of the pole with a mallet a few hundred times. It will become a magnet.
That process can create unwanted magnet fields when large objects are built from steel. It was especially important during World War II, because of mines that detected ship's magnetic fields, and various techniques were used to neutralise such fields. Ships also magnetise themselves simply by travelling aligned to the Earth's magnet field, from the combined effect of their velocity and the various vibrations on the ship. See Wikipedia Degaussing for further details.
Sticking two magnets together and pulling them apart again doesn't wear them out, either. Once again, your arms are supplying the necessary energy. However, when you do that, you're likely to expose each magnet to the other's field in a way that's not perfectly aligned, and that does increase the degradation rate, to a small degree.

Typical fridge magnets are not simple magnets. They are generally manufactured using a process that creates a Halbach array configuration. Adjacent elements in a Halbach array are orthogonal to each other, so their fields reinforce each other on one side, but counteract each other on the opposite side. Thus the bottom of a fridge magnet sticks to the fridge, but the top doesn't.


A Halbach array, showing the orientation of each piece's magnetic field. This array would give a strong field underneath, while the field above would cancel.

I expect that a Halbach array degrades faster because of the orthogonal field alignments. Fridge magnets are subjected to regular vibrations from the fridge, and old fridge magnets do seem to lose their strength after several years.

I learn something new here every day. Thanks.
