How many times do you need to drop a magnet for it to lose it's power?
How many times do you need to drop a magnet to the ground for it to lose it's power ?
Is there a way this is measured ?
Thanks!

You may enjoy my answer to a recent related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/824515/123208

Please provide more information. What material are you considering? What height is it dropping from?

This is exactly how magnets work: you can magnetize a a soft iron rod by pointing one end at the north pole and smacking the other end with a hammer. If you then reverse the rod and smack it again you can demagnetize it.
It requires work in order to line up all the domains within a chunk of ferromagnetic material and make it into a magnet, and it requires work to disorder it again. There is a quantity called the B-H product which is a measure of how hard or easy this task is and it is an integral part of the science of designing, building, and using magnets.

That's not how magnets work. Magnets work because of the alignment of electron magnetic fields throughout the metal - there's no power inside keeping it going. Electromagnets do require power, but that's supplied by electricity actively running through it. Dropping a magnet just doesn't do anything to it magnetically. I'd suggest maybe Youtubing some basic magnetism information.

Magnets can lose magnetization by dropping or other forces that are hard enough. While demagnetization doesn't arise from "losing power", it's still something the can happen
